# Reset State on Props Change

Tags: reactjs, state

So, I have three components(Search, Pages, HanddlesApi) plus App.js and I'm passing props around via functions to other child components with no problem.

The Search component passes it's state of userInput to HandleApi component and updates the api using componentDidUpdate. (this works great, np here).

I added the Pages component to update the api's page number so that the user can cycle through pages of content. This works, but with issues. The user can do a search and cycle though the pages, but if they enter a new query, they will land  on the same page number of the new query. For example, If
I searched "ducks" and clicked to the next page(2). Then did a search for "dogs" they would land on page two of "dogs"

So my question is how do I reset state for my Pages component only when a user enters a new query?

I saw that componentWillReceiveProps is being deprecated, so I can't use that.
getDerivedStateFromProps  seemed like it might be a good idea, but from what I read it should only be used in rare cases.

So, the two most likely options seemed to be, use componentDidUpdate in a way I don't understand or use key?

Overall I'm just confused on what to do

In my HanddlesApi Component I'm passing the follwoing into the API:

```
q: this.props.inputValue ? this.props.inputValue : 'news',
page: this.props.pageNum ? this.props.pageNum: 0
```

then..

```
  componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchNews()
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        if (this.props.inputValue !== prevProps.inputValue || this.props.pageNum !== prevProps.pageNum) {
            this.setState({
                news: []
            }, this.fetchNews);
        }
    }
```

Then in my Pages Component, I have

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'


class Pages extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            nextPage: 1,
            prevPage: 0

        }

    }
    handleNextClick = () => {
        this.setState({
            nextPage: this.state.nextPage + 1,
        })
    }

    handlePrevClick = () => {
        this.setState({
            prevPage: this.state.prevPage - 1,

        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className='pageNav'>
                <button className="PrevButton" onClick={() => {
                    this.handlePrevClick()
                    this.props.onNextButtonClick(this.state.prevPage)
                }}>Previous </button>

                <button className="nextButton" onClick={() => {
                    this.handleNextClick()
                    this.props.onNextButtonClick(this.state.nextPage)
                }}>Next </button>
            </div>
        )
    }

}

export default Pages
```

Search Component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class SearchBar extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            inputValue: ""
        }
    }
    handleChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            inputValue: e.target.value
        })
    }

    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        this.props.onSubmittedSearch(this.state.inputValue)
    }

    render() {
        //{this.props.onSubmittedSearch(this.state.inputValue)} 
        return (
            <section>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <label htmlFor="searching"></label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Search Something" value={this.state.inputValue} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    <button type="submit">Search </button>
                </form>

            </section>
        )
    }

}

export default SearchBar
```

App.js

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      inputValue: null,
      pageNum: 1

    }
  }
  // used to pass props from SearchBar to NewsList
  onSubmittedSearch = (inputValue) => {
    this.setState({
      inputValue: inputValue
    })
  }
  onNextButtonClick = (pageNum) => {
    this.setState({
      pageNum: pageNum

    })
  }



  render() {
    return (
      <main>


        <SearchBar onSubmittedSearch={this.onSubmittedSearch} />


        <NewsList inputValue={this.state.inputValue} pageNum={this.state.pageNum} />


        <Pages onNextButtonClick={this.onNextButtonClick} />
        <Footer />


      </main>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Please add the full code you are referring to. There is no input handling here.

Comment: Added more of the code. Does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should let App in charge of changing and holding the current page number. So you can reset it each time your search component submit. Here is a working exemple:

```js
class Pages extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (<div className='pageNav'>
            <button disabled={this.props.page <= 1} className="PrevButton" onClick={this.props.onPrevButtonClick}>Previous
            </button>
            <span>{this.props.page}</span>
            <button className="nextButton" onClick={this.props.onNextButtonClick}>Next
            </button>
        </div>)
    }

}

class SearchBar extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            inputValue: ""
        }
    }
    handleChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({inputValue: e.target.value})
    }

    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        this.props.onSubmittedSearch(this.state.inputValue)
    }

    render() {
        //{this.props.onSubmittedSearch(this.state.inputValue)}
        return (<section>
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <label htmlFor="searching"></label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search Something" value={this.state.inputValue} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                <button type="submit">Search
                </button>
            </form>

        </section>)
    }

}

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            inputValue: null,
            pageNum: 1

        }
    }
    // used to pass props from SearchBar to NewsList
    onSubmittedSearch = (inputValue) => {
        this.setState({inputValue: inputValue, pageNum: 1})
    }
    onNextButtonClick = () => {
        this.setState(state => ({
            pageNum: state.pageNum + 1
        }))
    }
    onPrevButtonClick = (pageNum) => {
        this.setState(state => ({
            pageNum: Math.max(state.pageNum - 1, 1)
        }))
    }

    render() {
        return (<main>
            <SearchBar onSubmittedSearch={this.onSubmittedSearch}/>
            <Pages onNextButtonClick={this.onNextButtonClick} onPrevButtonClick={this.onPrevButtonClick} page={this.state.pageNum}/>
        </main>)
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! Also, thanks for setting up the logic to prevent negative numbers. That would have been my next step.